# unable to startup database to free up space from recovery area:

Tags: oracle11g, rman

when i am trying to connect with database I faced this error---

```
'ORA-19815: WARNING: db_recovery_file_dest_size of 4102029312 bytes is 100.00% used, 
and has 0 remaining bytes available.'
```

so to delete obsolete file from flash recovery area i need to connect RMAN and to make the database open for internal use.but the database is not opened and throws this error

```
RA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel process ID: 5764
session ID: 5 Serial number: 3

USER (ospid: 6784): terminating the instance due to error 16038
ARC1: Archival started
Thu Feb 18 21:04:03 2016
ARC3 started with pid=23, OS id=6380 
Instance terminated by USER, pid = 6784
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you are on Linux, if you can't connect to DB to stop it you could just KILL the `pmon` or `smon` process to stop DB by finding the process id with:

```
ps -ef | grep pmon
```

Then you have 2 options:

1. Start DB in `NOMOUNT` and increase the `DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE` parameter `SQL> ALTER DATABASE SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE=300G` or
2. Startup DB in `MOUNT` mode and connect to DB with RMAN and delete some (or all) archivelogs `RMAN> delete archivelog all`, after this OPEN DB `SQL> alter database open;`

Comment: See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/169044/50938  for another solution